# String.Join overload not recognized

Tags: c#, resharper, .net-standard-2.0

I have code equivalent to `String.Join(',', new List<ulong>())` in a .NET Standard 2.0 project. I get two error from this line:

1. `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'char' to 'string'`
2. `Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ulong>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'`

These are the overloads of String.Join ReSharper shows on navigating to symbol:

[image]

I would assume that the second-last overload `public static string Join<T>(char separator, IEnumerable<T> values);` would be selected, but this doesn't happen.

When I changed my code to `String.Join<ulong>(',', new List<ulong>())` (explicitly specifying the generic type), the second error disappeared. Am I doing something incorrectly or is this a bug in VS?

Comment: Why don't you just use `","` ?

Comment: I _could_, but that's just circumventing the problem, isn't it?

Comment: No, and you're misunderstanding how all of the above APIs are meant to be used.

Comment: What type are you trying to assign the output to?

Comment: @Alex Just a `string`

Comment: @ClausJørgensen How do you mean?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, but the second-last overload indeed takes an `IEnumerable<>`? Regaring the downvotes - perhaps not, but I can't improve a post unless I know what's wrong with it.

Comment: netstandard 2.0 doesn't have overload with first parameter of type `char`. All `string.Join` overloads have first parameter of type `string`? Seems like Resharper shows you implementation of netstandard 2.0 not a contract.

Comment: I see only 5 `String.Join` overloads and none of them has `char` as a first argument though, not sure where did you get these 2 additional overloads.

Comment: Does IntelliSense suggest you overload with first parameter of type `char`?

Comment: @Fabio No it doesn't. I was unaware it was even capable of that.

Comment: This is a Resharper's "bug", In VS 2017 without Resharper `Go To Definition` will display correct overloads.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

.NET Standard does not have `String.Join` overloads with `char` as a first parameter, only .NET Core has them.

You have to use `String.Join(",", new List<ulong>())`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netstandard-2.0

Both R# and Rider show wrong info when navigating to symbol from .NET Core code, I can confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

.NET Standard 2.0 doesn't have overload with first parameter of type char. All `string.Join` overloads have first parameter of type string?

Seems like Resharper displays you implementation of netstandard 2.0 not a contract.

[standard.System.cs:3279](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/netstandard/ref/System.cs#L3279)

```
    public static System.String Join(System.String separator, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> values) { throw null; }
    public static System.String Join(System.String separator, params object[] values) { throw null; }
    public static System.String Join(System.String separator, params string[] value) { throw null; }
    public static System.String Join(System.String separator, string[] value, int startIndex, int count) { throw null; }
    public static System.String Join<T>(System.String separator, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> values) { throw null; }
```